# Souslin set and Projection of closed set

Tags: general-topology, descriptive-set-theory

(Souslin set definition)
Let $X$ be a topological space. A set $B \subseteq X$ is called Souslin set if there is a family of closed sets $\{F_s|s \in \mathbb{N}^{<\mathbb{N}} \}$ in $X$ such that $$B=\bigcup_{\sigma \in \mathbb{N^N}} \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} F_{\sigma\upharpoonright n}.$$

I want to prove that statement.

"If $A$ is Souslin set, then there exist a closed set $H$ in $X \times \mathbb{N^N}$ such that $A=\pi_X(H)$ where $\pi_X$ denotes the projection onto the first coordinate. "

I tried to prove it. Since $A$ is Souslin set, $A=\bigcup_{\sigma \in \mathbb{N^N}} \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} F_{\sigma\upharpoonright n}.$ I construct a set $H=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigcup_{s \upharpoonright n \in \mathbb{N}^n} F_{s \upharpoonright n} \times I(s\upharpoonright n),$ where $I(s\upharpoonright n)=\{t\in \mathbb{N^N}|t\upharpoonright n=s\upharpoonright n \}.$ I know that $\pi_X{H}=A$ but I'm not sure that $H$ is a closed set in $X \times \mathbb{N^N}.$ Is it true? How to prove that $H$ is closed in $X \times \mathbb{N^N}.$ Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of your set $H$ is a bit confusing. Perhaps it would be clearer to write it like this:
$$
H=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigcup_{s \in \mathbb{N}^n} F_{s} \times I(s),
$$
and then $I(s)=\{t\in \mathbb{N^N}\mid t\upharpoonright n=s \}$. It is indeed true that the projection of $H$ onto the first coordinate gives you $A$.

Then it is enough now to show that each union $F:=\bigcup_{s \in \mathbb{N}^n} F_{s} \times I(s)$ is closed. One key observation is the fact that the sets $I(s)$ for $s \in \mathbb{N}^n$ form a **clopen partition of $\mathbb{N^N}$**. From this you will be able to conclude the proof. In any case, the details are below.

> We will show that the complement of $F$ is open. So take some $(x,\sigma)\notin F$. Let $s:=\sigma\restriction n$, and let $U$ be open in $X$ such that $x\in U\subseteq X\setminus F_s$ (since $F_s$ is closed). Then $U\times I(s)$ is an open neighborhood of $(x,\sigma)$ that is disjoint from $F$. Happy new year!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I got it.

Comment: @MaurtenErik You are very welcome. If it satisfies you, you can “accept” it by clicking on the tick mark below the downvote button.